# WinUI3 CommunityToolkit DataGrid is not editable

Tags: c#, datagrid, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit

I have a WinUI3 app where I use CommunityToolkit datagrid to display some data from DataBase.
User needs to be able to edit this data, but for some reason datagrid is not editable

Here is a XAML code for datagrid:

```
<controls:DataGrid
            x:Name="dataGrid"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Width="880"
            MaxHeight="470"
            Margin="0,20,20,20"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            AlternatingRowBackground="Transparent"
            AlternatingRowForeground="Gray"
            AreRowDetailsFrozen="False"
            AreRowGroupHeadersFrozen="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CanUserReorderColumns="True"
            CanUserResizeColumns="True"
            ColumnHeaderHeight="32"
            FrozenColumnCount="0"
            GridLinesVisibility="None"
            HeadersVisibility="Column"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
            Loaded="dataGrid_Loaded"
            LoadingRow="dataGrid_LoadingRow"
            MaxColumnWidth="400"
            RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
            RowGroupHeaderPropertyNameAlternative="Range"
            IsReadOnly="False">
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Row.ZEILENNR}" Header="ZEILENNR"/>
                more columns like that
```

And here is code for populating the dataGrid

```
DatabaseHelpers.DataSet.MyDataTable dataTable = new DatabaseHelpers.DataSet.MyDataTable();
DatabaseHelpers.DataSetTableAdapters.MyDataTableAdapter adapter = new DatabaseHelpers.DataSetTableAdapters.MyDataTableAdapter();
adapter.Fill(dataTable, 1);
dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
```

adapter.fill is just a big select statement, which selects all rows from database based on certain value.

As you can see I specifically set IsReadOnly to "False" and yet I still cannot edit my datagrid

The binding works good, I can see all the data, it is just editing that does not work

EDIT:

I followed [Nick's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383426/nick) advice and tried to use ObservableCollection and CollectionView instead. Now my c# code looks like this:

```
DatabaseHelpers.DataSet.MyDataTable dataTable = new DatabaseHelpers.DataSet.MyDataTable();
DatabaseHelpers.DataSetTableAdapters.MyDataTableAdapter adapter = new DatabaseHelpers.DataSetTableAdapters.MyDataTableAdapter();
adapter.Fill(dataTable, 1);
ObservableCollection<DataRow> collection = new ObservableCollection<DataRow>();
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
          collection.Add(row);
    }
        
CollectionViewSource collectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
collectionViewSource.Source = collection;  
dataGrid.ItemsSource = collectionViewSource.View;
```

I am not sure if this is the optimal way, but it did solve the issue and now DataGrid is editable again.

Comment: I would highly discourage you from using DataTable and DataView.  You will be much better off with ObservableCollection and CollectionView.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is just editing that does not work"? You can edit the value in each cell but the value won't be applied back to the dataTable?

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding sorry for not being specific enough. By that I meant that I cannot edit cells in datagrid. If I double click any cell or press f2 nothing happens

Comment: @Nick I tried to use ObservableCollection. I could not use CollectionView, but I used CollectionVewSource instead and it still worked fine,  now DataGrid became editable again.  I edited the question with updated code

But why didn't it work with DataView?

Comment: @Rev1k, CollectionViewSource is the correct class.

As for the DataView, I am speculating now, but DataView is designed to work best with WinForm's DataGrid is now considered kind of obsolete.  When bound, DataView exposes a DataRowView for each row, which requires that BeginEdit() is invoked to modify a record.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't edit cells because you are not binding to properties with setters.

For example,

```cs
dataGrid.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Items>()
{
    Items.Add(new Item { Name = "A", Price = 100, Quantity = 1 });
    Items.Add(new Item { Name = "B", Price = 200, Quantity = 2 });
    Items.Add(new Item { Name = "C", Price = 300, Quantity = 3 });
    Items.Add(new Item { Name = "D", Price = 400, Quantity = 4 });
    Items.Add(new Item { Name = "E", Price = 500, Quantity = 5 });
}
```

where *Item* class is:

```cs
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Total => Price * Quantity;
}
```

you'll be able to edit only the *Price* and the *Quantity*.

**UPDATE**

If you can't use a class like *Item*, you could try by settting **IsReadOnly** on each column.

```xml
<controls:DataGridTextColumn
    Binding="{Binding Name}"
    IsReadOnly="False"
    Header="Name" />
```

I'm not sure this works with **DataRow** though.

Comment: But now I still don't use class, instead I just added all rows from DataTable to ObservableCollection and it works. I edited the question to include new code

Comment: @Rev1k, you will still be better off to use a class.  That will improve the performance.